# flutter sms feature not woking while building apk

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, telephonymanager

I am building a flutter application using the package `sms: ^0.2.4`, the App is working perfectly in debugging mode, but while I am trying to build apk file using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`, I am getting the exceptions like below:

```
Note: C:\Users\Dheeraj\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sms-0.2.4\android\src\main\java\com\babariviere\sms\telephony\TelephonyManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API
```

and

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sms:verifyReleaseResources'.        
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Dheeraj\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\Dheeraj\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

I also tried using `flutter_sms 2.0.1+2` package, But still no changes at all.I am getting the same exceptions as above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this package because this is completely new and it is a huge risk to use it in our app!!

Comment: thanks for your response, I also used "flutter_sms 2.0.1+2" package, but I am getting the same exceptions.Is there any way to do so, for directly sending the sms from flutter app